# Which arguments needed to load & execute class?

Tags: java

I have the following Java class files, where I'm trying to get one class file (Loadanotherfile.java) to load another class file. The loaded class file, (FileData.java), in turn, loads a text file.

Note: Running the FileData file separately works fine, so I don't think that's the issue.

See Below:

FileData.java:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;


public class FileData {

   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

       String file_name = "C:/Java/test.txt";

       try {
          ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
          String[] anyLines = file.OpenFile();

          int i;
          for (i=0; i < anyLines.length; i++) {
              System.out.println(anyLines[i]);

          }

       } 
       catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

       }

   }

}
```

Loadanotherfile.java:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Loadanotherfile {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       FileData.main(String[] args) throws IOException;  
   }

}
```

So the `Loadanotherfile.java` calls the main method in the `FileData` class. At first I just put `FileData.main()` in `Loadanotherfile` class, but the result error message said I needed the string arguments, so I put in the common "String[] args", as shown.

But then I get the ".class expected" or "required: value, found: class" errors. 
Then I tried to pass

```
String[] anyLines
```

as the argument, but that didn't work either.

So which arguments needed to be passed in so FileData executes from within Loadanotherfile?

I'm new to Java, started a week ago :0 so thanks in advance

Comment: change to `FileData.main(args);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the syntax for declaring a method to invoke a method in this line

```
 FileData.main(String[] args) throws IOException;
```

just pass the arguments of the main method of `Loadanotherfile` to the main method of the `FileData` main method

```
 // just pass the arguments of the Loadanotherfile main method.
 FileData.main(args);
```

or

```
 // pass a new empty string array 
 FileData.main(new String[]{});
```

and it will work.

You could also pass `null` to the FileData main method but this is not recommended because then if you use the arguments also have to check for `null`

```
 // possible but not recommended
 FileData.main(null);
```

But I'd like to suggest another approach. Do it the "correct" way.
Use a useful name for your FileData - actual it's something like a `FileDataService`. To read the lines use `Files` from the `java.nio.files` package and use a method name that represents the what it does like `loadFile`. Just to have a main method I've added the main method here.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;

public class FileDataService {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        new FileDataService().loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() {

        try {

            File file = new File("C:/Java/test.txt");
            List<String> anyLines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());

            for (String line : anyLines) {
                System.out.println(line);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }
}
```

In your `LoadAnotherClass` you can then write

```
public class LoadAnotherClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileDataService().loadData();
        // or even
        FileDataService.main(new String[]{});
    }

}
```

Comment: All your code works well. Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You dont require any arguments because you are not using it. You can try:

```
package test;

public class Loadanotherfile throws Exception{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileData.main(args);
    }
}
```

OR

```
package test;
public class Loadanotherfile throws Exception{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileData.main(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FileData.main(new String[]{});
```